# How can I convert one table result in to columns sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

[image]

How can I query this to get a result like this 
[image]

Can I use `pivot table` method for this. 
There can be n number of questions for one user. Any idea

Comment: yup, `pivot` could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join

to get your user Q1 value

```
JOIN `Question` `Q1` 
     ON `Q1`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` 
        AND `Q1`.`question name` = 'Q1'
```

to get your user Q2 value

```
JOIN `Question` `Q2` 
     ON `Q2`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` 
        AND `Q2`.`question name` = 'Q2'
```

query look like this

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, 
       `User`.`name`, 
       `Grade`.`grade`, 
       `Q1`.`mark` AS `Q1`, 
       `Q2`.`mark` AS `Q2` 
FROM   `User` 
       JOIN `Grade` 
         ON `User`.`id` = `Grade`.`user_id` 
       JOIN `Question` `Q1` 
         ON `Q1`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` 
            AND `Q1`.`question name` = 'Q1' 
       JOIN `Question` `Q2` 
         ON `Q2`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` 
            AND `Q2`.`question name` = 'Q2'
```

[image]

Comment: Actually there can be more than two questions and question name may change

Comment: @ebinmanuval so you want to convert question name as column? okay just wait

Answer (score 0):

This query will convert your data row to a column which will be alias as `Question name` of your question data

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(`Question name` = "', `Question name`, '",`mark`,NULL)) as ', `Question name`)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Question;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `Grade`.`grade`, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM `User` join `Grade` on `User`.`id` = `Grade`.`user_id` 
                  join `Question` on `User`.`id` = `Question`.`user_id` GROUP BY `User`.`id`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[image: User table]
[image: Grade table]
[image: Question table]
[image: Result of the query]

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49e74/1)